# Is there any possibilities to give <br/> after <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to give break up lines the entire sentences. So i put line break after

. This shows warnings. How can i come out this problem?

```
<ul>
  <br />
  <li>Details of available candidates will be sent to you</li>
  <br />
  <li>Cost of Service is as per Vacancy Check with Dial4jobz for the same.</li>
</ul>
<br />
<div id="Div8" style="display:none">Hot Resume</div>
</th>
```

Comment: Why was this tagged as `mvc` ?!

Comment: If i am using li margin means its not produce the answer. If i use the other option for before li using br means its not give the linespacing. What i do?

Comment: nobody noticed the illegal HTML. ´<br>´ before & between ´<li>´?

Comment: Then how will give break entire lines?

Answer (score 2):

No. Only list items may be children of a list.

If you want space between each list item - use a margin (applied with CSS).

```
li {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

If you want space between specific list items - reconsider your data structure. You might have a list of lists, or just a collection of lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a margin, you could add a break inside your list item, ie.

```
<li>Details of available candidates will be sent to you<br /><br /></li>
```

Comment: its always possible to use margin on a list item

Comment: Sure - but maybe there is already a margin and UT can't be changed. I agree that a margin is a much better way.